# Volvo V60 key needs new battery, will it 'forget' the car?

Tags: battery, volvo, key, keyless-entry

My Volvo V60 (2010/11) key needs a new battery. It's an electronic key for keyless entry. Technically I think it's a 'personal car communicator' (PCC).

A local locksmith can replace the battery but won't be able to reprogram the key. If I want it reprogramming I'll have to go to the Volvo main dealer which is further away (and more expensive).

When the old battery is taken out and the key loses power, will the key 'forget' the car it's associated with and need reprogramming? Or can we just swap over the old battery for a new battery and the key keep on working like nothing has happened?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cars it's not the key remembering the car, but the car remembering the key. Your Volvo should be no different. Reading through your [owners manual](http://az685612.vo.msecnd.net/pdfs/dd3ab1fddbf58b7d8166f509e72b73182a166d57/S60_Owners_Manual_MY11_EN_tp11834.pdf), it gives no warnings about taking this to the dealer for battery replacement, but rather gives you the owner instructions on how to change out the battery.

Here is the page taken from the owners manual:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No the car will not forget the key. Each Volvo key has a specific ID that even if you replace the battery, it doesn't change.

If you need help [replacing the battery in your Volvo key see these instructions.](https://www.youcanic.com/guide/change-volvo-key-fob-battery)